# apply function to extract random samples from elements of other list

Tags: r, list, data.table, apply

I have a data.table `clients` with 5 columns. I am interested in the column `product`, which can only have three values: `Product 1`, `Product 2`, `Product 3`.

The i have a list of three elements: `Product 1`, `Product 2`, `Product 3`. Each elements consist of 7 lists and so on - basically a nested structure. Here I am interested one element, which is a vector located at 4th level of the list.

> products[["Product 2"]]$CC$ID
> [1] "A" "B" "C"

Finally, for every row in my data.table `clients`, depending on which the value of the column `clients$product` i go to the list a randomly sample one value from the corresponding list element that corresponds to the product in `clients$product`. I tried to do this with `apply`:

```
apply(clients$product, 1, function(x) sample(products$x$CC$ID, 1))
Error in apply(clients$product, 1, function(x) sample(products$x$CC$ID,  : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

and

```
 apply(clients$product, 1, function(x) sample(products[[clients$product]]$CC$ID, 1))
Error in apply(clients$product, 1, function(x) sample(products[[clients$product]]$CC$ID,  : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

I guess i am doing something wrong with the `apply` ?

How ca my goal be achieved?

The objective of this entire exercise is to create a new columns clients$name. For each value of clients$name a random sample of 1 will be used from the list products$<corresponding products based on column clients$product>$CC$ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```r
 products <- list('Product 1' = list('CC' = data.table(no = c(1,2,3),
                                                       ID = c("A", "B", "C"))),
                  'Product 2' = list('CC' = data.table(no = c(1,2,3),
                                                       ID = c("E", "F", "G"))),
                  'Product 3' = list('CC' = data.table(no = c(1,2,3),
                                                       ID = c("I", "J", "X"))))

    clients <- structure(list(clientID = c(37796L, 20469L, 94233L, 68909L, 78700L, 
70727L, 85738L, 3441L, 29577L, 40235L, 17863L, 14273L, 46739L, 
60392L, 80945L, 62326L, 121555L, 127235L, 39507L, 41697L), product = c("Product 1", 
"Product 2", "Product 2", "Product 2", "Product 1", "Product 2", 
"Product 2", "Product 2", "Product 1", "Product 2", "Product 1", 
"Product 3", "Product 2", "Product 3", "Product 1", "Product 1", 
"Product 2", "Product 3", "Product 1", "Product 2"), gender = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("M", "W"), class = "factor"), status = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("EMP", "NEMP"), class = "factor"), age = c(40L, 
48L, 23L, 59L, 43L, 32L, 42L, 46L, 47L, 24L, 40L, 39L, 40L, 32L, 
58L, 45L, 48L, 38L, 51L, 22L), year = c(2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2018L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2018L, 2017L), exposure = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.930235934569214, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

random_product_id <- sapply(clients$product, function(x){
  sample(products[[x]]$CC$ID, 1)
})

clients$product <- random_product_id
```

Comment: I have added an explanation, hope that helps?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
set.seed(42)
clients <- as.data.table(transform(clients, ID=sapply(clients$product, function(x) {
  s <- products[[x]][[1]]
  unlist(s[sample(1:nrow(s), 1), "ID"])
})))
#    clientID   product gender status age year exposure ID
# 1:    37796 Product 1      M    EMP  40 2018        1  A
# 2:    20469 Product 2      M    EMP  58 2019        1  E
# 3:    94233 Product 2      M    EMP  45 2019        1  E
# 4:    68909 Product 1      W    EMP  48 2018        1  A
# 5:    20469 Product 3      M    EMP  58 2019        1  J
# 6:    94233 Product 3      M    EMP  45 2019        1  J
# 7:    68909 Product 1      W    EMP  48 2018        1  B
```

---

*Data:*

```
clients <- structure(list(clientID = c(37796L, 20469L, 94233L, 68909L, 20469L, 
94233L, 68909L), product = c("Product 1", "Product 2", "Product 2", 
"Product 1", "Product 3", "Product 3", "Product 1"), gender = c("M", 
"M", "M", "W", "M", "M", "W"), status = c("EMP", "EMP", "EMP", 
"EMP", "EMP", "EMP", "EMP"), age = c(40L, 58L, 45L, 48L, 58L, 
45L, 48L), year = c(2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2018L), exposure = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))

products <- list(`Product 1` = list(CC = structure(list(no = c(1, 2, 3), 
    ID = c("A", "B", "C")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000101ef0>)), 
    `Product 2` = list(CC = structure(list(no = c(1, 2, 3), ID = c("E", 
    "F", "G")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", 
    "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000101ef0>)), 
    `Product 3` = list(CC = structure(list(no = c(1, 2, 3), ID = c("I", 
    "J", "X")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", 
    "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000101ef0>)))
```